# iOS Developer Programs Specifics plus Unity3d export

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I have a few general questions about the iOS developer programs.
Please, accept these from a point a view of a small company with about 4 developers:

1. We've purchased an iPad, and developed a iOS application using Xcode and have been testing it using the simulator. The only legal path to test that application on the iPad itself is paying about 99$ to Apple ??
2. After paying the developer license, is there anyway of putting arbitrary applications on the iPad without using Xcode (without having the source or project of that same application) ??
3. If we buy the "iOS developer program - Company" versus the "individual" one, this means each one of us can deploy applications to different iPads (or it must be the same iPad for all of us) ??
4. Finally, Unity3d exports to iOS. What does it export: an application or the Xcode project (relates to my number 2 question! How will I be able to put that export into the iPad) ??

Please forgive me if these have already been answered. I could not find them. If so, please point me to them.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note, for 2016, in fact Apple in short allows you to test on your iPad, even if, you don't have a developer license yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, there is no alternative.
2. You cannot deploy some arbitrary app files, you must have an XCode project. I am not sure but I think you can write a make file and call all utilties at the command line.
3. I don't know about the company program, but you even with the individual program you can deploy to different devices. iTunes allows you to register 5 different devices on one account but your developer certificate enables you to test on up to 100 different devices (the iTunes limit of 5 stays valid thus you have register new iTunes accounts then).
4. Unity3D exports a complete XCode project ready to build for your device. You can modify some code (in certain situations you have to). I wrote an article in my blog about Integrating [3rd Party Static Libraries in Unity3D Generated XCode Projects](http://blog.scio.de/2011/08/managing-unity3d-generated-xcode.html). There you can get an idea of the process.

If you are registered as developer (I mean for free) you may have access to the [iOS portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) where you can find some more information.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are planning to evaluate Unity3D pro, I recommend answers.unity3d.com and their forum for questions as well.